# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras', after updating tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using vs code and my problem is I switched from "from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor" to "from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier, KerasRegressor"

My python is the last version and tensor flow and Keras has version 2.14.0. Each time I run my project, I get this error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.keras'

My code has the following imports:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV
# from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
# from tensorflow.keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier, KerasRegressor
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```

Comment: can you share a minimal version of your code with which you would get the same error. So it is easier for us to replicate